# DllImport PathCanonicalize on 64bit causes memory corruption

Tags: c#, 64-bit, pinvoke

I am trying to use the function PathCanonicalize using DllImport (PInvoke) on a 64 bit .NET assembly, and it causes memory corruption leading to all kinds bad behaviors (crash, exceptions out of nowhere, etc...).  (For example : System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.)

```
    [DllImport("shlwapi", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, EntryPoint="PathCanonicalize", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool PathCanonicalize( [Out] StringBuilder lpszDst,[In] string lpszSrc );

    public static string MyPathCanonicalize(string path)
    {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        if (!PathCanonicalize(builder, path))
            return path;
        return builder.ToString();
    }
```

I saw in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2533971/dllimport-error-system-accessviolationexception-with-manifest-file-and-c) that I should probably be using IntPtr instead of directly strings.  Can anybody show me how to marshal those in the input and output strings in PathCanonicalize?

The prototype is:

```
BOOL PathCanonicalize(
  __out  LPTSTR lpszDst,
  __in   LPCTSTR lpszSrc
);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the SDK documentation:

> lpszDst
>  [out] A pointer to a string that receives the
>   canonicalized path. **You should set the size of this buffer to MAX_PATH**
>   to ensure that it is large enough to hold the returned string.

Which you didn't do.  Fix:

```
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(260);
```

Answer (score 3):

Per MSDN for `PathCanonicalize` (emphasis mine):

> `lpszDst` *[out]*
>
> Type: `LPTSTR`
>
> A pointer to a string that receives the canonicalized path. **You must set the size of this buffer to `MAX_PATH` to ensure that it is large enough to hold the returned string.**

You'll need to initialize `builder` prior to the call:

```
public static readonly int MaxPath = 260;

public static string MyPathCanonicalize(string path)
{
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(MaxPath);
    if (!PathCanonicalize(builder, path))
        return path;
    return builder.ToString();
}
```

<strike>Also, note there is no `[Out]` on `lpszDst`, this is because the called method is not returning you a pointer, rather you're giving it a pointer to memory to write the canonicalized path.</strike> *(disregard, it appears to handle it fine with or without the `[Out]`)*

Comment: +1 Why put the [In] on `lpszSrc`? That's implicitly so due to marshalling conventions.

Comment: Copy paste fail, I've removed it anyways as it appears to work with the `[Out]` attribute.

Comment: The `[in]` and `[out]` annotations are for the C/C++ headers and you shouldn't copy them across to C#.

Comment: I agree in this instance, but disagree in the general sense. [`InAttribute` and `OutAttribute` are useful in some P/Invoke situations, but not this one.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/77e6taeh.aspx)